# Regular expression, matching word in sentence

Tags: regex

I have the following regular expression:

```
.*?\b(случајот)\b.
```

And i don't get what i need. I want to get the sentence in which the word appears, but when i try to get a sentence at the end of the text, i get the whole text. So i need any advice how to get the sentence between two full stops with the matched word.

I am using python and RegexBuddy for testing. Example:

```
**случајот** кај веќе сериозен политички и безбедносен инцидент јас на веќе гледам како на политички и безбедносен настан.
```

It just highlights the word only.

```
cell= db_conn.use_client().hql_query(db_conn.use_namespace(),"SELECT * FROM SE_doc_text WHERE ROW=                  \"da687a08e348c6791cbcc07c9a3057ef6473910b797839adabb0193e\" SCAN_AND_FILTER_ROWS LIMIT 1").cells 
#print cell[0].value
print "=============================="
text_nparsed = re.split( r"([^\.]*\bдаме\b[^\.]*)\.",  cell[0].value.replace("\\'","'")) 
return text_nparsed
```

Comment: You can post the code you're using, only the relevant part, of course, but it helps people figure out what you might be doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you want `([^\.]*\bслучајот\b[^\.]*)\.`

that selects anything without "." that includes the isolated word, followed by a ".".

Comment: Yes, tnx a lot, i should check what i did wrong, and study about regex more.

Comment: Man could you help me with the applying the regex on python, coz i tried and i get the whole text not the sentences.

Comment: are you using `r"([^\.]*\bслучајот\b[^\.]*)\."` to specify the regex?  if you don't use the `r` you need to double up the `\`s.

Comment: it works with exactMatch = re.compile(r"([^\.]*\"" + text_search + "\b[^\.]*)\.", re.UNICODE), but i have problem with utf it doesn't work with my native language. Any recommendations?

Comment: ufff.  probably not.  what version of java?

Comment: hey, you don't have an `r` in front of the second regexp above.  you need `re.compile(r"([^\.]*\"" + text_search + r"\b[^\.]*)\."` (you have `"\b[^\.]*)\."` with no `r`).